# how to read text file from computer on android

Tags: android, file

I Have Simple Android Application to Read the text file from hard drive of computer .

So i used as ,

```
try 
    {           
        File myFile = new File("E:\\myFolder\\"+name);
        Log.i("Test", "Path = "+myFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            UpdateArray.add(aDataRow);
        }
        myReader.close();
        return UpdateArray;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is Not Present at Location.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Something Went Wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
```

But it is "File is Not Present at Location." Toast.

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android device has no access to your desktop computer by default, and it most certainly does not have Windows drive letters.

Comment: @posteritysystem: Not really. You could create some sort of server that runs on your desktop (e.g., a Web server) and have your Android app communicate with that server. You could look into various legacy Windows SMB-style file-sharing protocols.